# Subtract a value from the Red channel only

Tags: image, imagemagick, gimp

Is there any easy way to subtract a value from the red channel?  For example, let's say a pixel has RGB(140, 30, 50), I would like to see subtract 100 from red channel only, hence giving RGB(40, 30, 50).  I know the image has redness over 100 so there should not be any problem hitting zero.

I am unfamiliar with Gimp although I thought it should be possible as well.  Or is there a simple ImageMagick command that does the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you need to work with values in the quantum range (default is 16-bits so 0 to 65535) or in percent. Subracting 100 is 100*100/255 = 39.2%, so in Imagemagick 6

```
convert image -channel r -evaluate subtract 39.2% +channel newimage
```

For example, I create a fully red image (r=255):

```
convert -size 1x1 xc:"srgb(255,0,0)" red.png

convert red.png -channel r -evaluate subtract 39.2% +channel red2.png

convert red2.png -format "%[fx:floor(255*u.r)]" info:
155

255-100=155; So we got the correct result above.
```

In Imagemagick 7, you could do

```
magick image -channel r -evaluate subtract "%[fx:100*100/255]"% +channel newimage
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gimp, two methods:

#### Method #1

- add a layer on top,
- fill it with dark red (RGB(100,0,0))
- put it in `Subtract` blend mode.

#### Method #2

- set the foreground color to RGB(100,0,0)
- set the bucket-fill tool mode to `Subtract`
- bucket-fill the layer